# Heroku: No such process type worker defined in Procfile

Tags: python-2.7, heroku

I'm trying to resize workers but the following message appears:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Ricardo:subastas ricardo$ heroku ps:resize worker=2X
Resizing and restarting the specified dynos... failed
 !    No such process type worker defined in Procfile.
```

this is my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn -k flask_sockets.worker chat:app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn workers and Heroku workers are not the same. 
Unicorn workers are in your web process, responding to requests.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn

Heroku workers are background workers.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing

If you need more ram et. al. for your workers, you just need to re-size the `web` type:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size

ex:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=n:2X
```

That reads: "scale to `n` web worker(s) at 2X dyno size", where `n` is the number of web dynos you want running.

Comment: actually I have "heroku ps:scale web=8:2X" but I'm not sure if I undertand how handle Heroku workers.